# Espresso android test throws Instrumentation run failed due to 'keyDispatchingTimedOut'

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

I have a list of android integration test written with espresso. When i run the test locally , all the test runs completely but when i run the test from jenkins all the test runs except one that makes a network connection.

I dont know why the test runs locally but not from a ci environment(with proper emulator configurations)

The major error displayed in the jenkins console log is :

[INFO] emulator-52981_unknown_sdk :     Run failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'keyDispatchingTimedOut'

Comment: Are you making the network connection from the Main thread ( UI thread )?